# How to Install ONOS using Bazel in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: build, bazel, ubuntu-20.04, mininet, onos

I have been trying to install ONOS using Bazel's new version i.e., Bazel-5.1.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for mininet/containernet. I have been having issues regarding Bazel build onos command. I have searched for the installation process all over and tried as well many. But have similar issues. Is there any link or article where there is a clear step-by-step procedure to do so? I am having a task for the installation which I need to finish in a week. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

The error I get:

```
    sendate@sendate04:~/onos$ bazel build onos
ERROR: The project you're trying to build requires Bazel 3.7.2 (specified in /home/sendate/onos/.bazelversion), but it wasn't found in /home/sendate/.bazel/bin.

Bazel binaries for all official releases can be downloaded from here:
  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases

You can download the required version directly using this command:
  (cd "/home/sendate/.bazel/bin" && curl -fLO https://releases.bazel.build/3.7.2/release/bazel-3.7.2-linux-x86_64 && chmod +x bazel-3.7.2-linux-x86_64)
```

I tried doing the steps given like downloading the same version and also tried to change the version in the .bazelversion file. But nothing succeeded in Bazel build.

Comment: I head while building the ONOS with bazel it doesn't the .oar file. You should go through this google group reference to understand more about it. https://groups.google.com/a/onosproject.org/g/onos-dev/c/tOjE8YHzcaU

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have gone through this google group long ago but I could not find any related answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.bazel —-version
If you didn’t download bazel version 3.7.x download it. If you download java version 11.You need create java default symbolic link. It will be /bar/lib/jam. . Test echo $PATH it will give ONON path. Then run sudo apt install —-reinstall build-essential. Build onos

Comment: As I mentioned, I also tried to run ONOS with Bazel 3.7 version. But with that version, the ONOS build is not successful, which ultimately results in ONOS run being unsuccessful. I will try the java part and post if I can run ONOS. Thank you for the response.